# Jersey @matrixparam and escaped semicolon in request

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

Using Jersey 1.8 I have a request as follow:

```
@DELETE
@Path("{itemids: [A-Fa-f0-9]+}")
public void deleteInstance(@PathParam("itemids") final PathSegment itemIdsPath) {
  ....
}
```

If I send an http request with path `/delete/1;2;3` then it works.  If however the semicolons are escaped, so the path looks like `/delete/1%3B2%3B3` then Jersey returns a 404 error.  Should Jersey be rejecting these latter requests or should it be decoding the path prior to matching the matrix parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should reject them. A URL encoding is used for the explicit reason to use a character of special meaning without this meaning. You could for example send a request `/delete/1;2;3%3B4` meaning the path with the segments `1`, `2` and `3;4` if those were valid names. Since you however specified a path name pattern of `[A-Fa-f0-9]+` for each segment, a request for the encoded name `1;2;3` is rejected and a 404 is returned.